# Having hana'ah from a melacha done on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hanaah-benefit

Is one allowed to have *hana'ah* on Shabbos from a *melacha* done, whether by him or anther, that day?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of deriving benefit from the actions done by a Jew on Shabbat the Shulchan Aruch ([OC 318:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=265) and Mishna Berurah and Biur Halacha there) distinguish between a number of cases:

- If a biblical prohibition was violated purposefully (deoraita bemeizid) then no one can derive benefit from it for the rest of shabbat, and the violator himself cannot derive benefit forever.
- If a biblical prohibition was violated accidentally (deoraita beshogeg) then no one including himself can derive benefit from it for the rest of shabbat and everyone is permitted to derive benefit after shabbat. (Some are lenient here in a case of need.)
- If a rabbinic prohibition was violated purposefully (derabanan bemeizid) then no one including himself can derive benefit from it for the rest of shabbat and everyone is permitted to derive benefit after shabbat. (Some question this ruling and forbid him from deriving benefit from it forever.)
- If a rabbinic prohibition was violated accidentally (derabanan beshogeg) then it is permitted to all to benefit immediately.

A caveat:

- Some hold that the above is true if violating the prohibition changed the object physically, but if something was carried between domains illegally then it remains permitted. Others dispute this distinction.