Sabbath candles accidentally lit too late
Excuse me if this is a silly question, I'm new here and don't know the customs.
I have heard about Sabbath candles. They have to be lit before Sabbath.
But what to do if they are accidentally lit after the Sabbath has begun? Snuffing them out, as far as I understand, is not allowed.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67813/759

Regarding your last bit, on Friday night we read "If one extinguishes a lamp because he fears idolaters, bandits, melancholia, or so that a sick person can rest, he is not liable. But if he does so to spare the lamp, to spare the oil, or to spare the wick, he is liable. Rabbi Yose absolves in all these cases except that of the wick, because he makes it into charcoal."

Yes, it can feel awkward, but the best course of action at that point is just to leave it alone.

Welcome to MiYodeya Gyro and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

It is correct that snuffing out a candle flame on Shabbat is one of the types of melacha (work) which are prohibited. It is termed M’chabeh (Extinguishing) - see this article for more details in particular this extract:

Because of m’chabeh, we may not douse or decrease a flame on Shabbos,
nor may we turn off electrical appliances. It makes no difference how
the fire is put out – cutting off the supply of oxygen, such as by
inverting a bowl over a flame is the same as pouring water on it.


Would it be allowed to light other candles (after Shabbat, of course) with this flame, or is it "tainted"? (If this is a valid separate question, tell me so I will ask it separately.)

I suggest asking this as a separate question
